# How do I make a point cloud in BY format have a "segment_index" attribute and store it in a plane index?

Tags: point-clouds, cgal

**Issue Details**

I'm using the example from CGAL's"Polygonal_surface_reconstrucCGAL's"Polygonal_surface_reconstruction/polyfit_example_user_provided_planes.cpp", I have split point cloud planes, each plane with different color information（PCD format）, but the algorithm provided by CGAL requires a file with a property named "segment_index"（PLY format）, I tried to convert with CloudCompare, but the converted PLY file don't has the property named "segment_index", I tried to find a way, but it all failed, I now have a point cloud with color information in pcd format, how can I convert it to a point cloud in ply format with "segment_index" attribute.If anyone can help me, thank you enough.

**Environment**
Operating system (Windows 64 bits):
Compiler: VS2019
debug mode
CGAL version: 5.5.2
Boost version: 1.82.0#1

Answer (score 0):

`CGAL::Polygonal_surface_reconstruction`  does not depend on PLY.  Read your colored points and fill the `std::vector.  In case your colors are RGB, there should be a limited number of colors that you have to map to an index in the range from 0 to the number of planes.  If you do not have normals in your file you must generate them.